# useState in useEffect Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Dates = ({ dates }) => {
  const [datesDivision, setDatesDivison] = useState({
    0: [{ date: 20200501, isVailable: true }],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setDatesDivison(divideDates());
  }, [dates]);

  const divideDates = () => {  //function to seperate dates
    let result = {
      0: [{ date: 20200501, isVailable: true }]
    };
    let num = Math.ceil(dates.length / 8); 
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      let item = [];
      for (let j = count; j < count + 8; j++) {
        if (dates[j] !== undefined) item.push(dates[j]);
      }
      count = count + 8;
      result[i] = item;
    }
    return result;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col2">
        {datesDivision[0].map((item) => (
          <div>{item.date.toString().substring(6, 8)}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// dates props
// [
// {date: 20200501, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200502, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200503, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200504, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200505, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200506, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200507, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200508, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200509, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200510, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200511, isVailable: true},
// {date: 20200512, isVailable: true},
//]
```

The bottom annotation is dates props.

To make pagenation I divide dates props into several groups by 8 units using divideDates function.

Then it will be like this.

```
{
0:[{date: 20200501, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200502, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200503, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200504, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200505, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200506, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200507, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200508, isVailable: true},],
1:[{date: 20200509, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200510, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200511, isVailable: true},
{date: 20200512, isVailable: true},]
}
```

So I assign split result using setDatesDivison in useEffect.

When I assign `{}` to  variable `result`(first line of divideDates function)

I got a error(Cannot read property 'map' of undefined).

So a map function didn't work.

But When I assign `{ 0: [{ date: 20200501, isVailable: true }] }` to
variable `result`(first line of divideDates function)

The rendering succeeded.

I think when first rendering setDatesDivison get ''result'' from `first declaration result` not from `return result`

I don't understand how the lifecycle works.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov. Ostensibly it's about `useEffect`, but it's really a deep dive into the lifecycle of components from a hooks perspective. Hugely useful.

Comment: Seems like your dates array is empty on initial render

Comment: You should assign result to `{0:[]}` because you are doing: `datesDivision[0].map` since datesDivision is result and will end up being an empty object when dates.length is smaller than 8: `let num = Math.ceil(dates.length / 8);`

Comment: Thank you everyone !.I solved this problem by conditional rendering like this ``datesDivision[0]&&datesDivision[0].map ... ``